# How to version my customized elementary OS

Tags: release-freya

I made some customization based elementary OS Freya, to understand each version easily, I wish to version my customization. for example, I wish the end user type

```
uname -a
```

then the output looks like

```
Linux 3.19.0-39-generic-version.1.0.0.custom
```

How can I achieve this? thanks in advance

Comment: This is being flagged as "unclear", and yet it seems perfectly clear, a little off topic, and no-one has even asked for clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

Actually `uname` shows information about the Linux kernel. So its output should only be changed if you have built a customized kernel.

However, if you have a custom distribution you should put this in the `/etc/issue` and `/etc/issue.net` files, like

```
user@machine:~$ cat /etc/issue
elementary OS Loki \n customized \l
```